# Anybody know the reason for the ‘Star Wars’ themed STARs into KATL?

Tags: instrument-procedures, sid-star

There are new RNAV STARs for arrival into Atlanta Class Bravo for KATL.  Does anybody know the reason a Star Wars theme was chosen for waypoint names eg TYFTR, WOKIE, NWHPE, etc?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably as simple as, somebody likes Star Wars.  There are a lot of similar points on one or two of the arrivals into KAUS as well.

Comment: [What's life without whimsy?](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/589705-what-s-life-without-whimsy)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a long established practice for the procedure developers to build the procedures around a theme. It helps with coming up with the necessary distinct pronounceable names for the waypoints.

My personal favorite is the RNAV (GPS) RWY 16 approach into KPSM. Flying from the IAF to the MAP and the Missed Approach Holding waypoint you fly:

ITAWT --> ITAWA --> PUDYE --> TTATT --> IDEED

which mimics [Tweety Bird's comment](https://youtu.be/4IGynnluDKo?t=9) when he sees Sylvester the Cat chasing him (for those readers who didn't grow up watching Warner Brothers cartoons).

Comment: Interesting that that arrival was in Portsmouth NH.  I had thought that the naming was a regional thing such as the FRDMM4 arrival into Washington, DC in honor of Sept 11, 2001 or the old IVNKA1 arrival into KPBI because of a certain notorious resident who owns property there.  I was curious if there was some sort of connection between the Atlanta area or airport authority and Disney/Lucasfilm that inspired the STARs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of choosing random names, some sort of a theme helps to come up with names one could easily pronounce, and because why not? :)

Another example:

[PIGLT FIVE arrival](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1810/pdf/00571PIGLT.PDF) into KMCO (Orlando Intl.)

i.e. HKUNA — MTATA — JAZMN — JAFAR — RFIKI (Disney references)

[This article](https://aerosavvy.com/navigation-name-nonsense/) from aerosavvy lists a few more interesting ones.

Comment: Well that one makes sense since it is an arrival into Orlando, home to Disney World

Comment: I was just trying to figure out if there was a connection between Atlanta and Disney or Lucasfilm

Comment: @CarloFelicione - How new is the procedure? Maybe it's to do with the *Star Wars Symphony* in Atlanta, that and Atlanta being known for the music industry.

Comment: That is definitely one possible explanation. Those arrivals are fairly recent additions – probably within the last year or so